# VBA: jumping out of a for loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

How do I achieve the following?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("Drop-down").Select
    n = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 1 To n
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Select
        *******************************************************
        If Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).Value = "" Then
            continue i
        End If
        *******************************************************
        If Worksheets("Misc").Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then
            Set validationRange = Range(Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))
        Else
            Set validationRange = Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i)
        End If
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=validationRange.Address
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't this a simple flow control case? I don't understand the need for special keywords to solve it:

```
For i = 0 To 10
 If Not condition Then 
    some other code
Next
```

**EDIT:** Or, in your code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("Drop-down").Select
    n = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 1 To n
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Select
        *******************************************************
        If Not Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).Value = "" Then
        *******************************************************
          If Worksheets("Misc").Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then
              Set validationRange = Range(Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))
          Else
              Set validationRange = Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i)
          End If
          With Selection.Validation
              .Delete
              .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
              xlBetween, Formula1:=validationRange.Address
              .IgnoreBlank = True
              .InCellDropdown = True
              .InputTitle = ""
              .ErrorTitle = ""
              .InputMessage = ""
              .ErrorMessage = ""
              .ShowInput = True
              .ShowError = True
          End With
     ********
      End If
     ********
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is indeed the best way of doing it. a few notes, in VBA, there is not 'Next i' it is simply Next

Comment: Ah, thanks Dave. I've never done any VBA, so I had to improvise a bit. ;) I edited the code to match your comment.

Comment: No problem, VBA being the weakly typed monster that it is might have accepted it anyway :S

Answer (score 2):

And to answer the other half of the question:

```
For n = 1 To something
    If condition Then
        Exit For
    End If
    ' more code

Next n
```

Comment: This doesn't do what I want, as it exits the for loop completely.

Comment: Your question asked how to jump "out of a for loop".  From your code, what you seemed to want was actually the "Continue For" statement, as answered by @Eric, I was adding "Exit For" for completeness.  As another answerer mentioned, using an Else statement is good too. There are many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't vb's keywords capitalized?

```
For n = 1 To something
    If condition Then
        Continue For
    End If

    ' more code

Next n
```

The `Continue` keyword does what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I think keywords auto-capitalize when you're in the IDE, but if you're just writing a VBScript file it ignores the case.

Comment: The VBA IDE window doesn't recognize your suggestions.

Comment: Drat. I'd assumed the syntaxes were the same.

Answer (score -1):

It's a too old question, but just for sake of **correctness and completeness in this page**, this is one of the situations that Goto can be used without resulting in Spaghetti code...

It leverages VBA's Loop to almost any other newer programming language, and provides VBA programmers with the same functionality described by Eric in another answer - but **Eric's answer does not works in VBA**:

```
    For n = 1 To something
        If needToExitLoopEntirely Then Exit For
        If condition Then GoTo ContinueFor        
        ' more code        
        ' ...           
        ' more code
ContinueFor: '<=this is a label; 
    Next n
```

Comment: In fact, I answered here because I tried the obvious and reasonable Eric's answer, only to discover that it not functions in VBA. So, for sake of correctness and completeness in this page, I registered the only correct and functioning way to Continue a For Loop in VBA.

Comment: Dear Mr. Downvoter: The two other answers (Tom and Eric) do not achieve what OP wants. Mine is the unique that achieve that, i e, answers **How do I achieve the following?**. Of course there are other ways to control flow, but this way is perfectably acceptable. I would be grateful if you could enlighten me with regard to why down vote this answer.